# What happens if I do not turn off the signal jammer?

Tags: deus-ex-human-revolution

I am naturally paranoid in the world of Deus Ex, so when someone is asking me to turn off a signal jammer on the Singapore mission so they can 'track me better' my natural instinct is to leave it on.  What are the consequences of leaving it on?

Comment: What "signal jammer" are you referring to?  I don't think they ever really used that term ever in the game.

Comment: the one in Singapore, the GPL jammer its a secondary objective to the mission: "Disable the Signal Jammer"

Comment: Hmm, I must have missed that one somehow or thought they called it differently.  The closest one I could remember was what I'm pretty sure they called "relays" and you had to disable them to find some girl for the bartender.  Is that the one you're referring to?

Comment: no, I'm way past that point, my mission is after the second hengsha visit.

Comment: Oh ok, I just probably haven't reached it yet.  I just returned there and am still in the process of revisiting all the areas in the city.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know for sure what happens if you leave it on. My guess is that nothing bad happens.

If you turn it off, you get waypoints for the other objectives you need to finish for this mission, which makes it much easier IMO. Otherwise you're most likely left to wander around the entire map looking for them, which makes the mission much harder than it needs to be.

That said, once you find one of the objectives you can get some slightly vague pointers to the other objectives. So if you want to leave it on, you're not completely on your own, but the mission is much easier with the jammer off.

Comment: if that's the only drawback, I'm just going to leave it on for fun then.  I always tend to thoroughly explore an area anyway and I relish a challenge like this

Comment: The GPL signal is also used to coordinate the distractions created by the 3 scientists, so if that signal is still jammed I'd assume the distractions won't happen in a coordinated fashion (or not at all). Just assuming though, I've turned the jammer off first thing :)

Comment: looks like there were no long term repercussions for leaving the jammer on as I completed that part of the mission doing so.  At some point during the mission, the jamming is turned off anyway.  Oh well